# Plot data file using PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a very large data file (.txt) organized as the following example:

```
0 1 1 . .

1 1 1 . . 

2 1 1 . .

. . . . .
```

I classically plotted a complex function `f(Y,\thisrowno(0),\thisrowno(1),\thisrowno(2),...)` using this data, this leads to many parallel curves. I want to connect vertically each node of a given curve with the corresponding node in the next curve. The resulting graph should look like a mesh.
Is there any easy way to achieve that?

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[legend entries={},
      xmin=-6, xmax=6,     ]                                 
     \foreach \i in {0,1,...,4}{     
     \addplot[thick]table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}, y expr=\i*\thisrowno{2}^2+\i]{test.txt};
     }      
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

where **test.txt** contains the following:

```
-5 -5  5

-4 -4  4

-3 -3  3

-2 -2  2

-1 -1  1

 0  0  0 

 1  1  1

 2  2  2

 3  3  3 

 4  4  4

 5  5  5
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It would be very nice if you could add a MWE which would make it much easier for us just modify the code and give an answer.

Comment: Do you really have empty lines in your txt-files?

Answer (score 1):

So you mean something like the following?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
    % if you want that the points should be connected, don't have empty lines
    % in the data file
    \begin{filecontents*}{test.txt}
        -5 -5  5
        -4 -4  4
        -3 -3  3
        -2 -2  2
        -1 -1  1
         0  0  0
         1  1  1
         2  2  2
         3  3  3
         4  4  4
         5  5  5
     \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.14,
    }
    % store the number of data rows in a variable (for later use)
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{test.txt}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\NoOfRows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-6,
        xmax=6,
        % we don't want to show any text in the `nodes near coords'
        nodes near coords={},
        nodes near coords style={
            % actually we only need them as `coordinate's
            coordinate,
            % and name them according to the following scheme
            name=node-\plotnum-\coordindex,
        },
        % !!! now comes a critical point !!!
        % Option a)
        % to make that solution work you have set the following option due to
        % technical reasons which is roughly:
        % normally the markers are first collected and are drawn *after*
        % `\end{axis}', in contrast to the `\draw' command. Said that, the
        % named `nodes near coords' are not available during the execution of
        % the `\draw' command
        clip marker paths=true,
    ]
        % use a loop to draw the plots (as before)
        \foreach \i in {0,...,4} {
             \addplot+ [thick] table [
                % (in this case this is much simpler than using `x expr=\thisrowno{0}')
                x index=0,
                y expr=\i*\thisrowno{2}^2+\i,
             ] {test.txt};
         }
        % now use a loop to cycle through each `\addplot' command
        % because we want to connect each point with the same "x value" with
        % the one of the next `\addplot', we use the `remember' feature of the
        % `\foreach' command
        \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially 0)] in {1,...,4} {
            % use another loop that cycles through each "x value"
            \foreach \j in {0,...,\NoOfRows} {
                \edef\temp{\noexpand%
                    \draw [green] (node-\lasti-\j) -- (node-\i-\j)
                        % these `node's are just drawn for debugging purposes
                        node [midway,inner sep=0pt,fill=green] {}
                    ;
                }\temp
            }
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]